# PYQT5 Simulating Window Menu MacOS

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pyqt5

I'm attempting to simulate the native MacOS "Window" menu in PYQT5. I am able to cycle through open windows via my menu and indicate the active window by setting its checked state to True.

[image: Current Window Menu]

I would like to also simulate the MacOS HID icon assigned when a window is minimized like this:

[image: Minimized Window Icon]

However, the closest I have been able to come is with a QIcon, which isn't quite right (the icon isn't quite right either, but I can live with that).

```
bring = self.view_menu.addAction('&Bring to Front', self.foo)
bring.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("diamond.png"))
```

[image: QIcon diamond]

Is it possible to have the QIcon displayed in the left menu column (aligned with the checkmark) or otherwise display a diamond for an action item like MacOS?  I didn't see any parms for the QIcon class that appeared to do this.